# workbench page shows "This site can’t provide a secure connection" on creating SPFx Webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I am new to SPFx, tried to create simple webpart using SPFx.
Referred from [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part).

*Followed these steps:*
-Installed nodejs
-Installed gulp & yomen using `npm install -g yo gulp` in powershell.
-Loaded sharepoint framework using `npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint`

-Now created a new directory using `md helloworldspfx`
-Navigated to the directory  `cd helloworldspfx`
-Tried to create the webpart using `yo @microsoft/sharepoint`
-Installed developer certificate `gulp trust-dev-cert`
-Tried to build & preview the webpart using `gulp serve`

Now workbench page opens up in chrome like this,
[image]

There is no error showing in the windows powershell.
 
Please help.

**SOLUTION:**
I have been using Node.js v8.9.
 With the help of [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/229397/58747) setting the `NODE_NO_HTTP2=1` environment variable to disable the experimental feature.
Like this, `$env:NODE_NO_HTTP2="1"` in powershell (`set NODE_NO_HTTP2=1` in CMD) to fix the issue.

Comment: Did you try deleting .gcb-serve-data directory and running gulp trust-dev-cert again. See https://github.com/Microsoft/gulp-core-build-serve#development-certificate

Comment: @Bunzab tried deleting *.gcb-serve-data* diretory & installed development certificate, but no change...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Node.js v8 by any chance? If so, there is a known issue with the http/2 experimental feature. You can disable it by setting the NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 environment variable. More information about the fix is available at https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1002.

Comment: Thanks guys! On Mac you run it on the command line like this: `NODE_NO_HTTP2=1 gulp serve`

Comment: I'm having the same issue.But this solution not worked for me. Still having the same issue. Node.js 9.4.0...

Comment: Node v9 (same as v8 btw) is not yet supported by SPFx. You should downgrade to at least v8, or even the recommended v6 which has been tested with SPFx.

Comment: Node v8 is now supported by SPFx but you still need to apply the $env:NODE_NO_HTTP2="1" PowerShell command in the same PowerShell window as you run gulp serve.

Comment: am using node v 10, am facing the same issue, even after setting the variable it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here - I guess in our network there's no certificate for localhost? Worked around it by changing to http in config > serve.json:

```
"initialPage": "http://localhost:5432/workbench",
"https": false,
```